# How to move shape node X and Y with accelerometer (Swift)

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have been looking around for ages to find a working solution for how to do this.

How am I able to move a circle shape node using the accelerometer in Swift. I need it to go left, right, up and down so the X AND Y coordinates need to change when the device is tilted.

I have tried lots of ways online and they don't work, they just end up moving the circle only one way or the circle goes the wrong ways etc.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you could try this:

```
var manager = CMMotionManager()
var destX:CGFloat  = 0.0


Player.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2, self.size.height/6.5)
self.addChild(Player)


manager.startAccelerometerUpdates()
manager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = 0.1
manager.startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue(NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()){
    (data, error) in

    let currentX = self.Player.position.x

    if data!.acceleration.x < 0 {
        self.destX = currentX + CGFloat(data!.acceleration.x * 1000)
    }

    else if data!.acceleration.x > 0 {
        self.destX = currentX + CGFloat(data!.acceleration.x * 1000)
    }
}


let action = SKAction.moveToX(self.destX, duration: 0.5)
self.Player.runAction(action)
```

just use the same code for the y. if you have any questions let me know!